# How to bind Route Property to Controller so that route property changes will reflect in controller

Tags: ember.js

Changing `isOpen` property in route should reflect it in my component. How can we accomplish this ?.

[Ember-Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/cab9e23a116e238aacae21bc4afe88e3?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

**routes/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  isOpen:true,
  setupController(controller,model){
    this._super(...arguments);
    controller.set('isOpen',this.get('isOpen')); //whenever i set route property, will this update controller?
    console.log('setupController');
  },
  actions:{
    toggleOpen(){
      console.log('before toggle - ',this.get('isOpen'));
      this.toggleProperty('isOpen'); //changing this route property is not reflected in controller.
      //this.controller.toggleProperty('isOpen'); //changing controller is reflecting.
      console.log('after toggle - ',this.get('isOpen'));
    }
  }
});
```

**controllers/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle'
});
```

**templates/application.hbs**

```
<h1>Welcome to {{appName}}</h1>
<br>
{{isOpen}}
{{my-component isOpen=isOpen toggleOpen='toggleOpen'}}
<br>
{{outlet}}
<br>
<br>
```

**templates/components/my-component.hbs**

```
my-component {{isOpen}}
<button {{action 'toggleOpen'}}> Toggle </button>
{{yield}}
```

**components/my-component.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions:{
    toggleOpen(){
      this.sendAction('toggleOpen');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep state on the route? State *should* be on the controller. Keep it there.

Comment: Thank you @Lux. that's how i implemented. but I am curious to understand reason for why route property update is not updating controller property when i said it in setupController hook..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `isOpen` is a [primitive typed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values) property. No matter if it was an object. [Sample Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8aa854a100b3ba256a3b36aa8998dc94?openFiles=routes.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs).

Or [more simplistic one](https://ember-twiddle.com/d8ada36911afc860d633875bd49d1214?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs).